# javascript / jquery - understanding jquery's post() and javascript's process() functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, process

I'm trying to post some data to a webservice and utilize the XML data it returns. I saw the example in JQuery's documentation for the post() function:

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
    function(data) {
        process(data);
    }, 
    "xml"
);
```

What does the process function do? What does the data look like? Do I assign this processed data to a variable? Just trying to get an idea of how I would utilize the values returned from this post().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does the process function do?

There is no such standard function. It's up to you to define it, so it will do whatever you tell it to do.

> What does the data look like?

That will depend on what does your web service returns. If it is XML, it will represent a XML tree. So for example if you service returns the following xml:

```
<foo>
    <bar>some value</bar>
</foo>
```

you could query the value of the `bar` node like this:

```
function(data) {
    var value = $('bar', data).text();
    alert(value);
}
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PrZze/) where you can see it in action.

Answer (score 4):

`process(data);` can be any function that you want to call that *does* something with the `data`. In most cases, you'd want to assign the data to an element or do some other massaging before displaying to the user.

Unless its very involved, you can skip calling a separate function too, e.g.:

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
    function(data) {
        $('#target').html(data);   // assuming data is a html string
    }, 
    "xml"
);
```

Taking it to process shape:

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
    function(data) {
        process(data)
    }, 
    "xml"
);

function process(data) {
    $('#target').html(data);   // assuming data is a html string

}
```

If your data in some other format, then you'd massage it to extract relevant bits or transform it in some way inside `process` or any custom function.

E.g., let's say  you get a JSON object back:

```
data = { "status": "success", "text": "Processed Succesfully" };
```

then in your callback, you'd check for status and the display message appropriately

```
function process(data) {
    if(data.status == "success")
        $('#target').html(data.text);   // assuming data is a html string
    else 
        alert("Error");
}
```